Get the next record order by date with same year in MariaDB
I have a table with some holidays, like this:



id
date
holiday_name




1
2000-10-24
holiday 1


2
2000-09-18
holiday 2


3
2000-01-04
holiday 3



The year is always the same. I want to get the next record after the record with the current date. I have this query now:
SELECT *
FROM holidays
WHERE date > CURDATE()
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 1

It works fine before the end of the year. But if the current date is in December and the next is in January, the query doesn't work because the year is the same and SQL considers it as a passed record. How do I get around this?

Next row - according to month and day?

@jarlh Yes, by month and day.

holidays UNION ALL holidays + INTERVAL 1 YEAR

You have the same year over and over, which is bad IMO. Still I see an id column on the table , but the dates are not in the same order as id , meaning date in id 2 is not greater than date in id 1. Can this design be fixed ?

@ErgestBasha If so then it should be replaced with current and next year. But I think that the table data is rewrited yearly. If not then WHERE date > CURDATE() will return nothing even on Jan, 1.

@Akina @Ergest Basha I just got the year 2000 as an example. It could be 2024 or 2025 and then WHERE date > CURDATE() works. I have the same year because the data was only entered once and will not be entered again. I want to use this query in a php script to show the previous, current and next holiday. Maybe there is a way to get rid of the year in the date?

Which MySQL version?

@jarlh MariaDB 10.11.6

MariaDB is NOT MySQL!!! edit tags list.

Pattern:
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), SUBSTRING(`date` FROM 5)) ndate
    FROM holidays
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, CONCAT(1 + YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), SUBSTRING(`date` FROM 5))
    FROM holidays
    ) normalized
WHERE ndate > CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY ndate
LIMIT 1

PS. Adjust for Feb, 29 which may produce incorrect date value.
